# Onclick function deleting all HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
</head>

  <button id="someid" onclick="open()">Open A Booster Pack</button>
  <button id="somid" onclick="view()">View Garage</button>
<body>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
<script>
  function open(){
  itms = ['2014 Nissan 350z', '2019 VW golf GTI ', '1995 Mazda 323 Protoge', '1990 BMW 8-series', '1990 ford mustang svt cobra', '1990 mazda rx7', '1990 nissan skyline gt-r'];
itm = itms[Math.floor(Math.random()*itms.length)];
    console.log(itm)
}
  function view(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ""+itm+""
  }
</script>
</html>
```

I have no idea why all the elements dissapear, even the DOCTYPE declaration vanishes when either button is clicked, for those who want to know I am trying to make a car collection card game website.

Comment: why are the buttons not in the body tag?

Answer (score 1):

[`open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) is already the name of a function that opens a new page, so when the button is clicked `open()` is called and an empty page is opened. Just change your function name:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
</head>

  <button id="someid" onclick="openpack()">Open A Booster Pack</button>
  <button id="somid" onclick="view()">View Garage</button>
<body>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
<script>
  function openpack(){
  itms = ['2014 Nissan 350z', '2019 VW golf GTI ', '1995 Mazda 323 Protoge', '1990 BMW 8-series', '1990 ford mustang svt cobra', '1990 mazda rx7', '1990 nissan skyline gt-r'];
itm = itms[Math.floor(Math.random()*itms.length)];
    console.log(itm)
}
  function view(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ""+itm+""
  }
</script>
</html>
```

Also, consider changing your code to use event listeners and variables instead. It is better practice:

```js
const itms = ['2014 Nissan 350z', '2019 VW golf GTI ', '1995 Mazda 323 Protoge', '1990 BMW 8-series', '1990 ford mustang svt cobra', '1990 mazda rx7', '1990 nissan skyline gt-r'];
let itm;

document.getElementById('open').addEventListener('click', () => {
  itm = itms[Math.floor(Math.random()*itms.length)];
  console.log(itm)
});

document.getElementById('view').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ""+itm+""
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="open">Open A Booster Pack</button>
  <button id="view">View Garage</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the name of your function. I'm not sure exactly where this code leads, but here's the fix:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head> </head>

  <button id="someid" onclick="openFunc()">Open A Booster Pack</button>
  <button id="somid" onclick="viewFunc()">View Garage</button>
  <body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
  </body>
  <script>
    function openFunc() {
      itms = [
        "2014 Nissan 350z",
        "2019 VW golf GTI ",
        "1995 Mazda 323 Protoge",
        "1990 BMW 8-series",
        "1990 ford mustang svt cobra",
        "1990 mazda rx7",
        "1990 nissan skyline gt-r",
      ];
        return itms[Math.floor(Math.random() * itms.length)]
    }
    function viewFunc() {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerText = openFunc();
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

btw, try to avoid innerHtml due to the potential risk it has. Try using innerText or innerContent. Hope it helps